# One of the few vs one of few

Tags: meaning, word-choice

When do you use *"one of the few"* and *"one of few"*?

Take for example:

> He went to a boarding school, one of few in the country.

and

> He went to a boarding school, one of the few in the country.

Is there a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We would only use *the few* when we want a noun phrase which points to a small group (often with a sense of them being an élite, but not necessarily).

> My work isn't popular, but the few who do enjoy it treat me well.

We would only use a bare *few* when pointing out the number but using another noun to show what we are talking about:

> There were many apples, but few were edible.
>
> There are few television shows that I enjoy.

We may use the two together for effect:

> We admire the bravery of the few who fell at Thermopylae, and the few who fell at Chaeronea, precisely because they were so few.

Here the last *few* is in this bare use, after two uses of "the few". (On a related, but only slightly on-topic note "The Few" capitalised refers to the pilots of the Battle of Britain).

In the case of your sentences, we have a clause that has a noun pointing out what we are talking about. After that we can either use the bare form and depend upon this noun to let us know what we are talking about, or we can use "the few" form and have that be a noun in that second clause.

So in this case, both are valid, and the meaning is the same, though arrived at in a slightly different way. All the sentences I give here use *few* and *the few* in ways that are outside of this overlap and couldn't have any of the uses switched.

Comment: That said, my intuition is that most native speakers would use _one of the few_ in this context, and corpus evidence seems to support this view. The COCA has 92 records for _one of few_, and 4835 for _one of the few_. The figures for the (smaller) BNC are 7 and 875. Of course, these figures also depend on context, but the difference is overwhelming.

Comment: @BarrieEngland I'm inclined to agree, but the first strikes me as in no way strange and I'm just as inclined to believe that most would accept it as such. What think you?

Comment: I rather think the first emphasises the paucity more than the second, but that may be fanciful.

Comment: @BarrieEngland well, I get that too, so maybe not that fanciful, or maybe we're being fanciful in the same direction. Likewise, the latter gives me a stronger impression of exclusivity as "the few" is so often used for élites. We're well into subtle nuance rather than correctness, to the point where I don't think those impressions could be well argued about beyond personal response.

Comment: @Barrie: I "sort of" agree that most native speaker would probably include that extra "the", if having it or not were the only alternatives. But it still seems a bit clunky to me - not least because of the repetition of the word "the". I'd much prefer *"...one of **only a few** in the country"*.

Comment: Heh. @FumbleFingers point on clunkiness makes me think there are two questions now - what would most native speakers use, and what would most native speakers use on the second draft!

Comment: @Jon: Google Books will quickly confirm that the overwhelming majority write [one of the few in the country](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22one+of+the+few+in+the+country%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but [one of only a few in the country](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22one+of+only+a+few+in+the+country%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is by no means uncommon. It's just my preference, is all.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes, but it's the preference questions I can't give a clear answer for that I muse on the most. That and who puts in all those clear mistakes that I certainly don't remember writing ;)

Comment: @Jon: I think the thing that puts *all those cleer mistakes* in must be a little routine the ELU backroom techies coded up for fun! I've noticed it sometimes messes up my otherwise deathless prose on the (originally, *perfect*) posts I make here! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7265/discussion-between-jon-hanna-and-fumblefingers)